# How can I properly close a socket connection in C# / WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, tcpclient

I implemented a little TCP connection to a program of mine, used for communication between a WPF application and a hosted Unity3D application.

I ran into a problem though when trying to re-open the window, the Unity3D application is hosted in.

```cs
public void SocketServer()
{
    IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    // use local m/c IP address, and
    // use the same in the client

    /* Initializes the Listener */
    myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8002);

    /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
    myList.Start();         

    MsgHandler placeHolderClass = new MsgHandler();
    Debug.WriteLine("The server is running at port 8001...");
    Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" + myList.LocalEndpoint);
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");

    s = myList.AcceptSocket();

    while (true)
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[100];
        int k = s.Receive(b);
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");
        string recived = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            recived += Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
        }

        Console.Write(recived);
        //ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        //s.Send(asen.GetBytes("Hey I Got This Msg" + recived));

        MsgUpdate = recived;

        placeHolderClass.GetInfosFromDB(recived);
    }
    //  Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");
    /* clean up */
}
```

Is just something I found online. If I keep it this way and re-open the window, it throws an exception that the port is already in use. Fair enough, I never closed the connection. I get that. Then I went ahead and added

```cs
void PageUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { 
    if(s != null) {
        s.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        s.Close();
    }
    myList.Stop();
}
```

But this doesn't work. If I do it without the if-check, it tells me that s is null, which doesn't make sense, because if I check if it is null it still throws me an exception,

```
 A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall.
```

A quick search leads me to believe, that the thread containing my socket is actually closed before I even call my PageUnloaded function.

But how do I fix this? Is this even a good approach? I read online that this implementation is very bad - but then five searches later this seems to be the best approach possible for my needs. I'm at a loss here, can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks! :)

Comment: PageUnloaded is too late for this code.  PageUnloaded event says that all objects on the page have been disposed.  So your socket was disposed without being closed.  If there is a PageUnloading event, use that.

Comment: When you create a TCP connection, the port which you used gets blocked for a while.(There is a timeout process but i don't remember how many seconds is it.)When i was working with TCP to send strings between two computers, i have encountered this problem.I was planning to creating a connection, sending message, closing connection and restarting the server with the same port.TCP didn't allow me to do that.I've solved with using UDP.Indeed using UDP is not a clear way to solve this problem.Your goals have to be matched with UDP standarts.Maybe UDP can help you.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem? I have a similar problem with a WPF app. I find there is no problem if I manually close the App by clicking on the X with the mouse. However, if I close the app programatically using Close() I find my SNMP UDP connections cannot be reestablished when the App restarts.